# Possible to retrieve actual price of Kindle ebooks via the Amazon Product Advertising API?

Tags: api, amazon-product-advertising-api

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, but I can't seem to find a response group that returns the actual price of a Kindle ebook. No problem getting the list price, but that's not useful to me if a book is discounted.

Is this supported by the API?

Answer (score 7):

Nevermind. Found the answer myself here:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=854

> Dear Product Advertising API Developers,
>
> Unfortunately at this time Offer Prices for Kindle Items are not
>   supported by the Product Advertising API. List Prices are however,
>   provided by the API.
>
> We apologize for the inconvenience.
>
> Sincerely, The Product Advertising API Team.

Comment: It seems that http://luzme.com/ and http://lendle.me/ are both displaying kindle prices. Are they likely scraping pages, then?